# Run script every 5 minutes on specific Seconds

Tags: cron, cron-task, crontrigger

I want to run a script every day, every 5 minutes at hour:minute:20 seconds between 09:00 and 22:00

I know how to configure the cron job between these hours and every 5 minutes, but it is very important to run it at hour:minute:20 seconds...

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Check the system time and compare that time to see if it :20 seconds?

Comment: You can run it together with a `sleep 300` (60*5 minutes).

Comment: @JGrice this way I should run the task every second... won't that be an overkill?

Comment: @WizMeister When it wants to run every 5 minutes, check the sys time, find the difference till it would be xx:20 and make it sleep for that long.

Comment: @JGrice that's awesome! Wouldn't it be better if I set the sleep to my cron? For example from 9:00 to 22:00 every 5 minutes, sleep for 20 secs then run the script

Comment: @WizMeister Yes, that works as well and is probably cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @JGrice

first one runs from 09:00 to 21:55

```
 */5 9-21 * * * sleep 20; script
```

and this one at 22:00

```
 0 22 * * * sleep 20; script
```

Comment: For the most common crontab implementation, `0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55` can be written as `*/5`

Comment: @KeithThompson that means that it can change to:

*/5 9-21 * * * sleep 20; script

right?